# $http get shortcut messing up program in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, http, angularjs-http

In the script below, I have posted a boiled down version of my code. It's essentially a simplified search engine.

The script loops through the $scope.list_of_fruit array, and filters it according to what is typed on a simple html input text box.

```
 <script>  
 var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);  
 app.controller("usercontroller", function($scope){  
      $http
      .get("test.php")
      .then(function (response) {
          $scope.myData = response.data.records;
      });

      $scope.list_of_fruit = ["apple", "banana", "pear", "kiwi"];

      $scope.complete = function(boxtext){  
           var output = [];  
           angular.forEach($scope.list_of_fruit, function(fruit){  
                if(fruit.toLowerCase().indexOf(boxtext.toLowerCase()) == 0)  
                {  
                     output.push(fruit);  
                }  
           });  
           $scope.filteredfruit = output;  
      }  
 });  
 </script>
```

This works fine and dandy, but when I paste that http get request up top, that is completely ***unrelated*** to that $scope.complete loop, the $scope.complete loop just stops working.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 app.controller("usercontroller", function($scope){
```

You don't have $http defined, so you are probably getting an javascript error.

Add $http to the function parameters:

```
 app.controller("usercontroller", function($scope, $http){
```

I created a snippet and this appears to work now

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("usercontroller", function($scope, $http){  
      $http
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data.records;
      });

      $scope.list_of_fruit = ["apple", "banana", "pear", "kiwi"];

      $scope.complete = function(boxtext){  
           console.log(boxtext);
           var output = [];  
           angular.forEach($scope.list_of_fruit, function(fruit){  
                if(fruit.toLowerCase().indexOf(boxtext.toLowerCase()) == 0)  
                {  
                     output.push(fruit);  
                }  
           });  
           $scope.filteredfruit = output;  
      }  
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myApp'>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-angular/master/angular.min.js"></script>
  
  <div ng-controller="usercontroller as vm">
    {{list_of_fruit}}
    {{filteredfruit}}
    
    <input type="text" ng-model="search"/>
    <button ng-click="complete(search)">Do something</button>
    
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```